# Keras when I try to train my model I get a " <no registered kernels>" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

when I try to create a model, it crashes when I try to train it 
code to create model, then train it

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))


opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

# Compile model
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy'])

# program crashes hear
history = model.fit(
    train_x, train_y,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),
    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint] )
```

I get the following error

> [seed=0, dropout=0, T=DT_FLOAT, input_mode="linear_input",
>   direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", is_training=true,
>   seed2=0] Registered devices: [CPU] Registered kernels:

complete stack trace

```
    K.batch_set_value([(v, 0) for v in self.variables])
  File "C:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3071, in batch_set_value
    get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "C:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 462, in get_session
    _initialize_variables(session)
  File "C:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 879, in _initialize_variables
    [variables_module.is_variable_initialized(v) for v in candidate_vars])
  File "C:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' used by node cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNN (defined at /Users/tpottel/programming/java/eclipse projects/BBitBotCoinUsing2/pythonproject/deeplearning/lstm-bitcoin.py:128) with these attrs: [seed=0, dropout=0, T=DT_FLOAT, input_mode="linear_input", direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", is_training=true, seed2=0]
Registered devices: [CPU]
Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>
\
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have CUDA set up on your system, or possibly no GPU. You could run with `LSTM` layers instead of `CuDNNLSTM`, but if the GPU acceleration is important you are going to need to configure your GPU. That's on the OS side, not Keras or Python.

Comment: That fixed the issue.  I got this code from a tutorial that did not talked about using a GPU.  Could you tell me what CUDA is

Comment: I just posted an answer with some links to get you started looking in to CUDA and CuDNN. If you have a GPU, try installing `tensorflow-gpu` with pip. If you don't, then just use the non-GPU LSTM layers.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from my comment, since that seemed to help: it looks like you don't have [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)/[CuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) set up on your system, or possibly no GPU. You could run with [`LSTM`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) layers instead of [`CuDNNLSTM`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/CuDNNLSTM), but if the GPU acceleration is important you are going to need to configure your GPU. That's on the OS side, not Keras or Python.

To use `LSTM` layers:

```
from keras.layers import LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# ...
```

If you have a GPU and you want to use it, try installing `tensorflow-gpu` with pip and seeing if you can't get GPU acceleration working. That's kind of a whole thing, so I encourage you to do some research online and then come back to SO when you have specific questions.